# Installing a signed release variant of my app fails (built in Android Studio 3.4.2)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building my app's release variant, but when I try to install it, I get

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]`

There is no `android:testOnly` attribute in my AndroidManifest.xml either.

My app runs fine if I run it from Android Studio, but the built APK won't install from the command line.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to the gradle.properties file:
`android.injected.testOnly=false`